# reading strings until blank line then reading more

Tags: java, arrays, iteration, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a program which reads in lines from a file with Scanner. When there is a blank line, I want to process the lines already seen and stored in a String array list. Then I want it to skip to the next line in the file until it sees a blank line again.. then process those lines, until the file is fully read.

I can't seem to wrap my head around doing this? So far my program works for the set of lines up until it reaches the blank line but then doesn't progress.

The processing I want to do can be seen in my code after the `while scan.hasnextLine()` loop has finished.

Thanks for your help.

```
public static void main(String[]argv){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //read in the line from stdin, if it's empty, then break out OR process it
    while (scan.hasNextLine()){
        String tempLine = scan.nextLine();
        if (tempLine.equals("")){
            break;
        }        
        columnCount = tempLine.length();
        tempArray.add(tempLine); //add temp line to string array initial

        rowCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("rowcount: "+rowCount);
    System.out.println("columnCount: "+columnCount);

    //set the 2D array to the right size
    epidemicArray = new char[rowCount][columnCount];

    //populate 2d array with strings from tempArray
    updateArray();
    System.out.println("original array:");
    printArray();

    //copy populated 2d array to another array
    copyArray(epidemicArrayCopy);


    //iterate over array to get final state
    do{
        getFinalState(epidemicArray);
    } while (countChanges > 0);
    printArray();

}
```

Comment: According to ur code your loop get break when it finds the first blank line. So it will not read the rest of the lines. Better to try little bit harder ;)

Comment: Try encapsulating the logic of processing a batch of lines in a function and calling the function over and over again...

Comment: @Alejandro I tried that but then if I set rowCount to 0 in that batch of lines function, it calls rowCount ++ when it returns back. And i can't put the rowCount++ before I process the lines cos if it's blank line I don't want to add to rowCount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's where your problem happens:

```
if (tempLine.equals("")){
    break;
}
```

When you get to `break` you exit the loop. Make a function called `processArraySoFar` and call that instead of `break`. Assuming `tempArray` is an `ArrayList`:

```
if(tempLine.equals("")){
    processArraySoFar(tempArray);
    tempArray = new ArrayList(); //make a fresh ArrayList to use until the next line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work.

```
public static void main(String[]argv){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //read in the line from stdin, if it's empty, then break out OR process it

    while (readSome(scan)){}
}

public void readSome(Scanner scan) {
    while (true){
        if (!scan.hasNextLine()) {
            return false;
        }
        String tempLine = scan.nextLine();
        if (tempLine.equals("")){
            break;
        }
        columnCount = tempLine.length();
        tempArray.add(tempLine); //add temp line to string array initial

        rowCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("rowcount: "+rowCount);
    System.out.println("columnCount: "+columnCount);

    //set the 2D array to the right size
    epidemicArray = new char[rowCount][columnCount];

    //populate 2d array with strings from tempArray
    updateArray();
    System.out.println("original array:");
    printArray();

    //copy populated 2d array to another array
    copyArray(epidemicArrayCopy);


    //iterate over array to get final state
    do{
        getFinalState(epidemicArray);
    } while (countChanges > 0);
    printArray();

    return true;
}
```

Here we do your processing on each chunk read.

**EDIT:**
I suspect you need to add:

```
columnCount = 0;
rowCount = 0;
```

to the beginning of the readSome method.

**End-edit**

**Edit 2**

You probably need this too:

```
tempArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Near the column/row count resets.

**End edit 2**

Or maybe you wanted:

```
public static void main(String[]argv){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //read in the line from stdin, if it's empty, then break out OR process it
    while (scan.hasNextLine()){
        String tempLine = scan.nextLine();
        if (tempLine.equals("")){
            continue;
        }
        columnCount = tempLine.length();
        tempArray.add(tempLine); //add temp line to string array initial

        rowCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("rowcount: "+rowCount);
    System.out.println("columnCount: "+columnCount);

    //set the 2D array to the right size
    epidemicArray = new char[rowCount][columnCount];

    //populate 2d array with strings from tempArray
    updateArray();
    System.out.println("original array:");
    printArray();

    //copy populated 2d array to another array
    copyArray(epidemicArrayCopy);


    //iterate over array to get final state
    do{
        getFinalState(epidemicArray);
    } while (countChanges > 0);
    printArray();

}
```

The difference here is that we continue, not break, so we read the rest of the lines.  But we only process after reading the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you have is that you are using `break` to get out of a loop while what you really want is to skip the line and continue.

So basically all you have to do is remove the break and alter a bit of your code to look similar to this:

```
String tempLine = scan.nextLine();
if (!tempLine.equals("")){
    columnCount = tempLine.length();
    tempArray.add(tempLine); //add temp line to string array initial

    rowCount++;
}
```